# Launch javaFX app from java code

Tags: java, graphics, javafx-2, javafx

I have a JavaFX card game currently running for single player. I want to enable multiple players playing over TCP socket connections, for which I have a simple client/server skeleton program written in java.

My problem is: the server/client code is in java. How do I launch the javafx app from the client java code, and then update it based on the gamestate returned from the server?

Simple server-client loop will be: client sends action, server updates gamestate, and echoes it back out to client.

```
client pseudo-code

if(!clientGUI.isInitialised())
   initJavaFXapp();  // I am struggling to do this

//keep reading from server 
if(obj instanceOf gameState)
    javaFXGUI.update(obj)
```

I am beginner to using javaFX, and I utilised the graphics aspect as my app is based on it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming `MyApplication` class extends `javafx.application.Application` you can launch it next way:

```
 javafx.application.Application.launch(MyApplication.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do i get an instance of the javafx class? So that I can update components on it using public methods belonging to the javafx class?

Comment: I also get an error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class Project1.runJavaFX is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application`. 

Where runJavaFX is the java class, and inside that I have put `            `Application.launch(TableGUI.class)`. where tableGUI is the javaFX app. @SergeyGrinev

Comment: just rechecked, works with JavaFX 2.2 which version do you use? Anyway as a workaround you can create static method in `TableGUI` which will call `launch`. And call that method from `runJavaFX` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created a static method and launched it via that. I am trying to update gui component's, say a text on it, how do i invoke a method of TableGUI : i have to get an instance somehow or do i make other setter methods static as well?

Comment: unfortunately there is no good way to get an instance of an Application. You either create a static field or introduce some service interface there you can "register" you application object.